# $\bmod p\!:\ b\not\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, b^{-1}\equiv b^{p-2}$ for $\,p\,$ prime

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisor-sum

I have found something like this:

> $(((a^{x}-1)mod\ p)* ( a-1) ^ {p-2})mod\ p = \frac{a^{x}-1}{a-1} mod \ p $

After taking some examples and considering the place I took this from this should be true.

If my reasoning is right, from the ecuation above we get that $(a-1)^{p-2}$ is the modular inverse of (a-1).

1.Am I correct?
2.What is the origin of such an "ecuation" as the one above?

P.S. The formula is a part of the Divisors sum formula.

***Edit due to comment:***

What I ment by what is the origin, is how do you get from the fraction in the right side, to the ecuation in the left side. I want a detaliated explication since I'm new to modular arithmetics.

Comment: There's no need to $\bmod~p$ individual terms when you're $\bmod~p$'ing the whole equation. Rather than deriving the modular inverse fact from the highlighted congruence, you would derive the highlighted congruence from the modular inverse fact (which is Fermat's little theorem, basically Lagrange's theorem for the group of units mod $p$). This equation is not special enough to talk about "origins"; it's just one of the many many things that could arise in the everyday operations of modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [little Fermat,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) $\,\rm mod\ p\!:\ b\not\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow 1 \equiv b^{p-1}\equiv b\cdot b^{p-2}\Rightarrow\ b^{-1}\equiv b^{p-2}$

Yours is the special case $\rm\, b = a\!-\!1,\,\ a\not\equiv 1$.

We implicitly used the *uniqueness* of inverses. Proof: $ $ if $\,\rm c',c$ are both inverses of $\,\rm b\,$ then

$$\rm  c' \equiv c'(bc)\equiv (c'b)c\equiv c $$

This holds very generally since the above proof uses only commutativity and associativity.

Answer (score 2):

1) If $a-1$ is not divisible by $p$, then you are correct that $(a-1)^{p-2}$ is the inverse, modulo $p$, of $a-1$.  This is, in fact, Fermat's Little Theorem: if $b=a-1$, then $p$ divides $b^p-b=b(b^{p-1}-1)$—hence, when $p$ does not divide $b$, it divides $b^{p-1}-1$.

(on the other hand, if $p$ divides $a-1$, then $a-1$ has no inverse.)

2) The origin appears to be you.